# TxtBox setfocus does not focus correctly

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a textbox for username. The format is firstname.lastname and I am trying to check to see if the box has a "." in the name to validate the string. The messagebox works correctly, but whenever "Ok" is clicked, it still goes to the next textbox instead of going back to the txt_Name to edit the name entry.

```
Private Sub txt_Name_AfterUpdate()

    Dim username As String

    username = UCase(Me.txt_Name.Value)
    Me.txt_Name.Value = username


    If InStr(1, txt_Name.Text, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Me.cb_Shift.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please use the following format:" & vbCrLf & _
               "FirstName.LastName")
        Me.txt_Name.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For such kind validations please use `BeforeUpdate` event and set Cancel variable to True if the value is invalid. You won't need SetFocus in this case

Comment: I don't have a cancel variable, please explain

Comment: Each text box has BefeoreUpdate event, Cancel variable is a parameter of this event, it generated automatically when you create this event.